# sap ui5 Binding Odata northwind

Tags: javascript, sapui5, northwind

i want to bind some values from Odata Service Northwind V2 in the list items but the Output shows no Data. i have already given the Service in the Manifest. 
it would be helpful if someone help me with this issue.

```
<List id="listid" items="{model>/Products}"     headerText="Products">
    <items>
    <StandardListItem
        title="{ProductName}"
        description="{model>ProductId}"

        type="Navigation" />

        </items>
</List> 

enter code here
```

**Manifest:**

```
    "title": "{{appTitle}}",
    "description": "{{appDescription}}",
    "dataSources": {
  "datamodel": {
    "uri": "/destinations/northwind/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/",
    "type": "OData",
    "settings": {
      "odataVersion": "2.0"
```

.......
 `"model": {
        "dataSource": "datamodel"`

**neoapp**:

```
 "path": "/northwind",
  "target": {
    "type": "destination",
    "name": "northwind"
  },
  "description": "Northwind OData Service"
},
```

Comment: Northwind! Hadn't thought of that in years.

Answer (score 0):

the path in your neoapp needs to fit the uri in your manifest.json or the other way around, e.g.

```
..
  "path": "/destinations/northwind", // add /destinations
  "target": {
    "type": "destination",
    "name": "northwind"
  }, 
..
```